# how to obtain excel-like JTable headers

Tags: java, excel, jtable, header

I would like to create a JTable whose global layout would look somewhat like excel's.

To get this result I used the Groupable Header's code from crionics.com, but as you can see components of the header are not aligned vertically.

Moreover, I would like to be able to write multi line text in the rows of the documents where it's needed, but I am not able to get both multi line cells, multi line header cells, and groupable columns to work at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the JIDE Grids. If you are working for commercial project, it's cheaper to buy these kind of things than write them yourself.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer but I prefer writing this on my own, as I don't want to add 3rd party libraries to my code right now

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, you already have colspan and rowspan headers. What are you missing?